# Trigger delete BEFORE INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers

I created the following trigger in Mysql:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER delete_G8_dados_indicadores_antes_insert
BEFORE INSERT
   ON G8_dados_indicadores FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   delete from G8_dados_indicadores where id_indicador=NEW.id_indicador and ano = NEW.ano;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

The idea is that before entering a record in G8_dados_indicadores table, the system triggers the trigger automatically removing existing records. But to run an insert, mysql returns the following error:

1442 - Can't update table 'G8_dados_indicadores' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

What can it be?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation in mysql, you have to find a workaround. In this particular instance, I would not even use a trigger, but either use [replace into ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) or [insert ... on duplicate key update ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) instead of an insert.

`Replace into` deletes the old row and inserts the new one, `insert ... on duplicate key update ...` does an update instead of an insert, if the record already exists.